# column-wise count of row-wise maximum for multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For example i have some data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [-6, -5, -4], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I want the output to be `{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}`

Where one row has an absolute max in column 'a' (2nd row where the absolute max of that row -6, is column 'a'), 0 rows have absmax in column 'b', and 2 rows have absmax in column 'c' (3 and 9)

Comment: `df.abs().idxmax(axis=1).value_counts().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Damn @piRSquared, you beat me to the punch.  Probably worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

piR has a nice solution using `idxmax` in the comments.

```
df.abs().idxmax(axis=1).value_counts().reindex([*df], fill_value=0).to_dict()
# {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}
```

As an alternative, you can bypass the reindex step if you convert the result into a `Categorical` array:

```
pd.Categorical(df.abs().idxmax(axis=1), categories=[*df]).value_counts().to_dict()
# {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}
```

There's no reason to prefer one over the other, this is just another way of doing it.

Comment: **GOLFED:** `{**pd.Categorical(df.abs().idxmax(1), [*df]).value_counts()}`